# How to retrieve value from plugin and store in variable?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using a plugin to count chars, called wordcount. How do I access the value (the variable) that counts the amount of characters, and store it in a of my own variable? I need to store the value in my own js script.

I was thinking of maybe using getData(), but not sure what to instantiate.

Comment: Are you talking about extracting char count from this [wordcount plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wordcount)?.

Comment: Yes, Marek, that's the one; and in this case, that's what it means; in a more general sense, it could be any plugin that performs a calculation, and accessing its variables. In this case, as a continuation from my previous question, I'd like to advise the user of the minimum amount of chars that she must write in the textarea (like stack does). jQuery innerHTML, and count length, won't do, for some reason. I've been thinking of sending the text with ajax to a php script that uses strip_tags, counts the length, and sends back the info...but that sounds too much for such a casual calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a global variable (declaring it at the beginning of the .js file).